# Change UIImageView mode iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

If I have an UIImageView with the mode set to center for example how can I change it to something else such as aspect fit with code?

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 30):

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

you can set it to any of the following

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
UIViewContentModeRedraw,
UIViewContentModeCenter,
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight
```